# Missing C partition after installing ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Hello guys a few days ago I bought 250GB SSD drive and decided to switch from windows 7 to linux.

Now I have never installed linux before so I must have made an error during the process.

First thing I did is on my laptop hard drive (500GB) I deleted everything that was in "C" partition with `minus` button during ubuntu install interface and installed ubuntu on my new SSD drive.

Now after finishing everything I've noticed that my "C" drive space is missing. On old hard drive I had two partitions "C" and "D". "C" had roughly 150GB and "D" had 350GB.

I can see old "D" partition and It"s data fine but I cannot see my former "C" partition.

It's like I lost 150GB of space. Can anyone help me with this ? What could  I do to fix it and again see/use my former "C" partiton ?

EDIT: Now I don't what to recover files from my former C drive I just to be able to use it again. It should just be empty partition now.

EDIT: Sorry guys for confusion I lost `space` not `data`.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x91721898

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda3       314793675 976768064 661974390 315,7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x117a410e

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 488394751 488392704 232,9G 83 Linux



$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST500LM021-1KJ15 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 3      161GB  500GB  339GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  250GB  250GB  primary  ext4         boot
```

Comment: You literally said you deleted everything that was in your C partition using the minus button during the installation process. I'm confused right now...

Comment: @Tooniis There was `-` button and I pressed while choosing C partition

Comment: Linux doesn't use drive labels like windows does. If you installed Ubuntu on what was originally your C partition, it will be called something like sda, and all your data from windows will be lost.  If you can boot into Ubuntu, you can see a graphical representation of your partitions by running the program `gparted`.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can use ubuntu just fine and I don't care about lost data I just want to be able to use that hard drive space again.

Comment: same way you do in windows...go to your disk management tool, select the empty partition, create new partition.  gnome-disks is one tool you could use, fdisk is a command line tool, many others.

Comment: Oh, you're not missing **data**, you're missing **space**. Please edit your question to clarify that. I'm retracting my close vote.

Comment: What does `sudo parted -l` show? Do you have/can you get a Live Boot USB stick? It'a always better not to boot from the hard disk you're editing.

Comment: @waltinator I have added details for `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output of `fdisk`, you have about 150GB of free (unpartitioned) space on disk sda, before the start of partition sda3. You can create a new partition there.

I think you're confused because you deleted a partition, but you thought you were deleting the *contents* of the partition.

Comment: Yeah I think that is it. Can you tell how should I proceed. How can I remake that partition so I can use that space again ?

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 You can use a program like GParted, Disks, or `fdisk` to create a new partition.